# how to print {done} in the same column in makefile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to print `{done}` while compiling some files in makefile. like that:

```
Compiling src/execution/ft_cd.c:                                {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_check_path.c:                        {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_echo_pwd_env.c:                      {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_execution.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_exit.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_export.c:                            {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_init_env.c:                          {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_linked_lists.c:                      {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_linked_lists_rest.c:                 {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_pipes.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_redirection.c:                       {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_unset.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_utlis.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_debug.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_get_tokens_op.c:                      {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_get_tokens_word.c:                    {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_get_tokens.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer.c:                                    {done}
Compiling src/expansion/expansion.c:                            {done}
Compiling src/parse/check_syntax.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/parse/parser_debug.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/parse/parser.c:                                   {done}
Compiling src/readline/readline_debug.c:                        {done}
Compiling src/readline/readline.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/readline/get_next_line.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/main.c:                                           {done}
```

but instead The output come like that:

```
Compiling src/execution/ft_cd.c:                                {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_check_path.c:                                {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_echo_pwd_env.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_execution.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_exit.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_export.c:                            {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_init_env.c:                          {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_linked_lists.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_linked_lists_rest.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_pipes.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_redirection.c:                               {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_unset.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/execution/ft_utlis.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_debug.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_get_tokens_op.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_get_tokens_word.c:                            {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer_get_tokens.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/lexer/lexer.c:                            {done}
Compiling src/expansion/expansion.c:                            {done}
Compiling src/parse/check_syntax.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/parse/parser_debug.c:                             {done}
Compiling src/parse/parser.c:                           {done}
Compiling src/readline/readline_debug.c:                                {done}
Compiling src/readline/readline.c:                              {done}
Compiling src/readline/get_next_line.c:                         {done}
Compiling src/main.c:                           {done}
```

This is the rule where I print this output:

```
$(OBJECTSDIR)/%.o : $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c
    $(HIDE)$(MKDIR) $(dir $@)
    $(HIDE)/bin/echo -n "Compiling $<:"
    @echo "\t\t\t\t$(GREEN){done}$(RESET)"
    $(HIDE)$(CC) $(FLAGS) -I $(HEADERSDIR) -I $(LIBFT_HEADER) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354092/bash-add-trailing-spaces-to-justify-string

Comment: There are better ways out there, but you could use a carriage return in your echo to reset to column 0 before adding the tabs. `@echo -e "\r\t\t\t\t\t{done}"`

Comment: @RyanHaining I tried your solution and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot.

Comment: @DarkSide77 it's rough. the `{done}` will always appear at the same spot, overwriting other characters if they happen to be there

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a POSIX shell such as bash or dash, use the `printf` builtin instead of echo with tabs:

```
    @printf "Compiling %-40s$(GREEN){done}$(RESET)" "$<:"
```